# Tomcat 8.5 Scanning jars for TLD's recalcitrant log

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8.5

I am using Tomcat 8.5 and I am trying to remove this single line in my log files:

> INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.
>   Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that
>   were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs
>   during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

I have tried everything I can think of to remove this INFO message :

- All of my logging levels in conf/logging.properties are at FINE
- I have uncommented all of the optional level clauses.
- I have tried all of the file names I have listed in the jarsToSkip and all files in my local lib file and in the tomcat/lib files are listed.

The log file always tells me the above, I can't seem to find the file on my own?  Is there some other way?

Comment: You didn't mention if you looked for other "hidden" logging.properties files, as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284581/7748072)

Comment: I read the post you referenced and it seems that the accepted answer is the only one for tomcat 8 but references location '{workspace_loc}\Servers\Tomcat v7.0 Server' which I can't seem to sort out.

Comment: No, I am no talking about the accepted answer but about the answer that you open with the link, from Whome. He suggests to check if you have other logging.properties coming with your own apps.

Comment: Found the problem, not with the use of any technology.  Another webapp on the same server had a jar with the name changed so it didn't match the pattern.  Argh!