# Why does Tomcat default to scanning for TLDs, a framework specific artefact

Tags: java, tomcat7

Many people use Tomcat as an excellent Servlet container who don't use JSPs/Taglibraries.

There are many mature component oriented Java UI frameworks available now which have no need for older technologies like JSP/Tag libraries so I question why scanning every Jar for these older style Tag library artefacts is the default action for Tomcat 7 and which needs to be turned off in order for Tomcat to start up in reasonable time.

Wouldn't it be better if Tomcat treated JSP as 'just another' UI framework that it supports but not one that it is intrinsically bound to?

What is the quickest way to configure Tomcat 7 to turn off this scanning and make it work in 'Tomcat 6' mode?

Comment: Maybe in recognition of the fact that many (most) people use servlet containers (requiring the core of the Servlet API) without the JSP component (which is just one of the many Java UI frameworks now available) there should be some consideration given to separating the raw Servlet API from any specific Java UI framework like JSPs. I recognize that, in the early days of the Servlet API, there was really only 'one true' Java UI framework but that ship has long since sailed. Separating JSP from the servlet API seems to make sense.

Comment: Irrespective of whether removing JSP from Tomcat would be a good thing, this Question is little more than invitation for people to provide opinion-based Answers.  If people are serious about this, they should propose it to the Tomcat team.  Anything else is essentially non-productive.

Comment: In reference to your updated Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489665/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-taglib-scanning-in-tomcat

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to several of your statements here, JSP is a separate specification from Servlets. What you're arguing with is the way Tomcat is defined. Tomcat is a *product,* and it is defined to include an implementation of the JSP framework. If you're suggesting that the JSP implementation should be removed from Tomcat you won't find much support.

Comment: Yes, remove JSP from Tomcat, or remove it from the Servlet API spec and make JSP spec a separate spec that can depend upon the Servlet API spec but the Servlet API should need no dependency or references to JSP.

Comment: There was an iPad-contributed typo above. You *won'* find much support, either in the Tomcat team or its millions of users. I doubt that you will find any. NB JSP *already is* a separate specification from Servlets. What you're arguing with is the way the Tomcat product is defined.

Comment: @EJP - I was going to pick you up on that typo.  But then I thought you might have meant it :-)

Comment: @StephenC No, you were right the first time. If I was in favour I hope I would have expressed it somewhat more elegantly :-|

Comment: @nos According to EJP JSP is not part of the servlet specification.

Contrary to what I said above (can't edit - dang!) I don't think JSP should be removed from Tomcat - but I believe Tomcat should be 'less coupled' to JSP. i.e. don't auto scan for it's TLD artifacts by default because many people are using Tomcat as a container for newer Java UI frameworks (i.e. not JSP) where these TLDs etc., are not used so why scan by default and force users to have to 'disable' this scanning 'feature'?

Comment: Answering my own question:

Use org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.jarsToSkip= in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.

The value is a comma-separated list of additional filenames of JARs that Tomcat will *not* scan for TLDs.